# echo Div visibility using CSS and PHP?

Tags: php, css

I am trying to echo a CSS style in php. basically I want to make a Div visible.
the Div's visibility is set to hidden in the css stylesheet and i need to make it visible in an else statement in php.

I am using this code:

```
<?php
} else {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        #apDiv1 {
           visibility:visible;
        }
        </style>';
}
?>
```

but that doesn't work! it doesn't make the Div visible. I tried it this way as a test and this way worked and it echo-ed hello world:

```
<?php
} else {
    echo 'hello world';
}
?>
```

so is there any other way to do this? am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the HTML for that div?

Comment: There just isn't enough information in you question for us to know what it is exactly that you want to do.

Comment: why the downvote? I don't understand why some people are just waiting for someone to post a question here and just downvote the question without any reason!

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx: Can we see your HTML? Normal case the above should have worked. Maybe there is some other problem somewhere else.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx As you said to the answer with most votes, you tried it and it doesn't work. People sometimes just answer by assuming without knowing what you actually want. Maybe that's why someone down voted.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx: And to answer the other question. Do not bother about *a* down-vote. If the question has enough detail and shows that analysis was done prior to asking the question, it will eventually get into the positive. I am not saying that asking for reason is wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try like

```
<?php
    } else {
 ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            #apDiv1 {
                visibility:visible;
            }
        </style>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Or directly give the div style like

```
<?php
    } else {
?>
     <div id="appDiv1" style="visibility:visible"></div>
<?php }
?>
```

Even you can put `!important` if any other styles are applied on that div.

Answer (score 3):

try `visibility: visible !important;`, or `display: block`.

Comment: I did try that before i posted this question and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript instead of css

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('apDiv1').style.visibility = 'visible';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do directly on the div:

```
<div id="apDiv1" <?php if(/* Your condition */){ /* Do something */ }else{ echo 'style="visibility:visible;"';} ?>></div>
```